# Elm - Toggling fps based on model state (fpsWhen)

Tags: signals, frame-rate, modelstate, frp, elm

Is there a way in elm (or rather, what is the proper way) to stop and start the `Time.fps` function based on the state of the application (stored in the model)? For example, in an application I'm working on, when the pause key is pressed, the state field of the model is set to Paused. I would like the fps to stop until it is set to Playing again. My initial thought was to use `Time.fpsWhen`, but it throws an error. I've thrown together this example which is structurally similar to my application to demonstrate.

```
import Signal
import Time
import Keyboard
import Text
import Graphics.Element (Element)

---- MODELS ----

type State = Running | Stopped
type Action = ToggleRunning | DeltaTime Float

type alias Model = {state : State, counter : Float}

---- UPDATE ----

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model = case action of
  DeltaTime dt -> { model | counter <- model.counter + dt }
  ToggleRunning -> { model | state <- if model.state == Running then Stopped else Running }

---- VIEW ----

view : Model -> Element
view model = Text.asText model

---- INPUTS ----

stateToggleKey : Signal Action
stateToggleKey = Signal.map (always ToggleRunning) <| Signal.keepIf identity False Keyboard.space

timeDelta : Signal Action
timeDelta = Signal.map DeltaTime <| Time.fpsWhen 20 (Signal.map (.state >> (==) Running) model)

input : Signal Action
input = Signal.merge stateToggleKey timeDelta

model : Signal Model
model = Signal.foldp update {state=Running, counter=0} input

main : Signal Element
main = Signal.map view model
```

You can see it "running" [here](http://share-elm.com/sprout/54eeab36e4b09711f39c2e31).

My assumption is that it isn't working because `model` and `timeDelta` are recursively dependent on each other, but I'm not sure. In any case, how should I go about stopping the fps while the application is in a paused state? Do I have to store the running state separately from the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general recursively defined signals are not supported. The compiler just isn't good enough to be able to check for wrongly defined recursive values yet. You may want to look at a related question/answer on SO about recursive definition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22284451/859279

If your game can only be paused by spacebar, and only be unpaused by some input that isn't dependent on the game state, you can actually use `fpsWhen`:

```
onDown s = keepIf ((==) True) True s

playing = Signal.merge (always False <~ onDown Keyboard.spacebar) (always True <~ onDown Keyboard.enter)
-- turn the two arguments to merge around for the playing signal to start with True

-- another way where spacebar toggles pausing:
playing = Signal.foldp (\_ b -> not b) False (onDown Keyboard.spacebar)

timeDeltas = Time.fpsWhen 60 playing

inputs = (,,) <~ timeDeltas ~ playing ~ etc

state = Signal.foldp update startState inputs

main = view <~ state
```

Comment: Definitely an option, at least for user input based conditionals. What would I have to do if I wanted a timer in the model to tick down until 0 when the app should return to a menu? The timer ticks down as part of the game loop and time can be added based on user interaction. Ultimately, however, the event that triggers the state to change from `Playing` to `Menu` is the timer hitting 0, which can only be triggered by `Time.fps`. I don't want `Time.fps` ticking on the menu, so I again end up reliant on the state of the model, and this one doesn't seem as clear to work around. Thoughts?

Comment: One option is to try to [hack around this limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28278235/859279). Another is to accept `Time.fps` for now, and wait for the linked hack to be altered into a language feature, [which seems to be the plan](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elm-discuss/CgHtzkrwlpA/85qLig9TGgoJ).

Comment: Looks like I'll just keep `Time.fps` running all the time for the time being and eagerly await version 0.15. Thanks for the detailed response by the way!