# "input is undefined" error when using WebSockets in Elm

Tags: websocket, elm

I'm trying to set up a simple example using WebSockets in Elm, but I keep getting the run time error "input is undefined". The console does not give me any line number in my elm file or anything like that.

I was trying to use WebSockets in a large project, and I kept getting the error "a is undefined", so I decided to make this small example to try and isolate the problem.

I wrote some code that receives messages containing numbers from the websocket. It increments the numbers, and then sends the new numbers back out over the web socket. The server does the same thing, sending back the number incremented by 1 to the client.

Here is the elm code:

```
import Graphics.Element (Element)
import Signal
import Signal (Signal)
import Text
import Window
import WebSocket
import String

type State = Num Int
           | StateErr String

input : Signal String
input =
    WebSocket.connect "ws://localhost:4567/test" sendToServer

sendToServer : Signal String
sendToServer =
    Signal.dropRepeats
        (Signal.dropIf (\str -> str == "") "" (Signal.map formatReply state))

formatReply : State -> String
formatReply state =
    case state of
        Num n -> toString n
        StateErr str -> ""


stepState : String -> State -> State
stepState str state =
    case (String.toInt str) of
        Ok n -> Num (n + 1)
        Err str -> StateErr str


display : (Int,Int) -> State -> Element
display (w,h) state = Text.asText state


state : Signal State
state =
    Signal.foldp stepState (Num 0) input


main : Signal Element
main =
    Signal.map2 display Window.dimensions state
```

I tested the server side, and it's working fine, so I definitely do not think that the server is causing the issue.

When I tried the code in Firefox, I get "input is undefined". When I run it in Chrome, I get "Cannot read property 'kids' of undefined".
In Chrome, upon looking at the stack trace it seems that when the code goes to run, **input is undefined**. Is this a bug with the WebSocket library?

I'm very new to using Elm, so I'd appreciate any help/advice on using websockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned that the cause of my troubles, is that as of now the WebSockets library in elm is not fully implemented. I also learned that I can accomplish my goals using ports, and then implementing the websocket in javascript.

I added the following javascript to my html file:

```
var game = Elm.fullscreen(Elm.SlimeWarz, {rawServerInput: ""});
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4567");

socket.onopen = function(){
  console.log("Socket has been opened.");
}

socket.onmessage = function(msg){
  game.ports.rawServerInput.send(msg.data);
}

game.ports.sendToServer.subscribe(sendOverWebsocket);

function sendOverWebsocket(str) {
  socket.send(str);
}
```

Then in elm, I can send data using a ported Signal called sendtoServer

```
port sendToServer : Signal String
```

and I can view all the data I receive through the ported signal rawServerInput

```
port rawServerInput : Signal String
```

Comment: Your original problem is not necessarily websocket related. I'll try to find time for a full answer later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

I'm going to use part of [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28278235/859279). **I think [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29567438/859279) to use ports and do the websocket part in JavaScript is better** than the hack I described in that answer, but you may still want to look at it. Once Elm 0.15 is released this problem should go away entirely because of a language feature and the revamp of `Websocket` (`Http` gets revamped too btw).

### Context: Reason for error

The reason you get the runtime error is because of a [compiler bug](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/295). The compiler only generates correct code on recursive functions, while it accepts *any* recursive value. Notice that your `input` depends on `sendToServer`, `sendToserver` depends on `state` and `sContext: tate` depends on `input`.

## Context: Code architecture

Those kinds of cyclic signals are usually a sign of bad program architecture. You can find more on that subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261359/mutually-dependant-signals/22284451#22284451). **But your architecture is not at fault here.** The problem lies with the `Websocket` library which doesn't steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!